# Download SVG files

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg

I want to download files using JavaScript which have svg extension.
Actually I have around 300 svg URLs which I want to download via code.
I have tried with this code

```js
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
downloadURI("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg", "helloWorld.svg");
```

but by this a tab with the given URL is getting opened, I want it to be downloaded.

Here is the example link I am trying to download
[Example Link](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg)

Comment: Never post screenshots of your code. Paste your codes in your question instead. Edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) closely, you will find this `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs, or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes.

Also, Internet Explorer and iOS Safari do not support this attribute at all. In short, don't rely on this attribute for the cross-browser experience.

Hint: You can use a server-side script to add `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: *never* refer to unofficial tutorial sites like w3schools. Use official documentation like MDN and W3C.